# How does this precision full wave rectifier work?

Tags: led, diodes, comparator, circuits

I am making a VU meter, and I need to rectify the audio signal for the IC comparator chip. I found this circuit in the datasheet, but I am unsure of how it works.

[image]

I understand that the LF351 op amp is needed to overcome the threshold voltage of the diodes, but what is the purpose of the LM307 op amp? Is it just a buffer? Why not just use another LF351?

Comment: if this is feeding directly into a comparator circuit, have you considered a window comparator circuit instead of precision rectifier -> comparator?  depending on your specific needs it might be small, cheaper, more accurate

Comment: @JonRB Probably using an LM3915 or something like that.

Comment: ah, fair enough.

Comment: There are better designs that are non-inverting single supply that work down to a few mV https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuit-collections/lt1078-absolute-value-circuit-full-wave-rectifier.html#cc-overview

Comment: There are bipolar circuits, implemented on silicon, suitable for Gigahertz RF power detection, taking the logarithms, and generating RSSI Relative Signal Strength Indicators. Your cell phone will use such a circuit.

Comment: @JonRG Yes, this is feeding into an LM3915.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The circuit that you posted is much simpler, but the one I posted in the original question can be used for average or peak detection with the addition of a few more diodes. Peak detection would be better for a VU meter I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather tricky schematic; to understand it, you need to consider 2 case whether the input signal (after C1) is positive or negative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwAFqG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When it is positive, D2 is blocked and you can remove it and study the simplified schematic.
OA1 behaves as an inverting amplifier with gain -1 whose output is \$V_2\$: \$V_2 = - V_{IN}\$.
Then OA2 is an inverting summer: \$V_{OUT} = - {R_5 \over R_4} V_{IN} - {R_5 \over R_3} V_2 = - V_{IN} - 2 V_2 = V_{IN}\$.

When it is negative, D1 is blocked and you can remove it and study the simplified schematic.
OA1 behaves as a follower with input to ground and output at \$V_1\$: \$V_1 = 0\$.
Then OA2 is an inverting summer: \$V_{OUT} = - {R_5 \over R_4} V_{IN} - {R_5 \over R_2 + R_3} V_1 = - V_{IN} - V_1 = -V_{IN}\$.

As for the choice of OA1 and OA2, when $V_{IN}$ crosses zero, the output of OA1 needs to go quickly from -0.6V to 0.6V. You need an op amp with a hich slew rate. There is no such requirement for OA2.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your question, the most likely answer is that the LF351 was more expensive so they used a cheaper op-amp where high **slew rate** was not required. The LM307 is/was a 741 type of op-amp, slow and semi-precision. Slew rate is less than 1/20 that of the LF351.

It's important to have a high slew rate amplifier in the LF351 position because there the output of the input op-amp should move quickly from -0.7V to +0.7V (ideally instantly) since one diode or the other should always be conducting.

---

To see how it works, consider when the AC-coupled input is > 0, say V1. Current flows through R1 and R2 and D1 so the left side of R3 is at -V1, thus the current flowing into the node at pin 2 of the LM307 is Vin/R4 - Vin/R3 + Vout/R5, so the output voltage (ignoring C2 for the moment) is +Vin

[image]

---

When the AC-coupled input (right side of C1) is < 0, call it -Vin, D2 conducts  (keeping the op-amp output from straying too far from ground, reducing the demands on slew rate) and the current flowing into the node at pin 2 of the LM307 is -Vin/R4 + Vout/R5, so Vout = -Vin (again ignoring C2).

[image]

---

C2 acts to average the output voltage with a time constant of C2*R5.

In  the second case there is a resistance R2 + R3 between pin 3 of the LM307 and pin 2 of the LF351. Since both nodes are always at virtual ground there is (ideally) no effect from that 200K resistance.

Comment: When the AC-coupled input is positive (V1), you mentioned that the left side of R3 is at -V1. Why is that? Is it because the gain of the 351 is -1, making the voltage in the feedback loop through D1 negative?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The gain is -1, **measured at the right side of R2**. The gain from the output of the LF351 will have a slightly different value and a relatively large offset, but we don't care much about that. To drive the inverting input of the LF351 to exactly 0V the voltage at that point must be -V1 (assuming no op-amp bias current and resistors exactly matched).

Comment: Awesome I understand now. I ordered the components, should be a while before they get here though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When wiring up the LF351 amplifier, do I need to use a dual supply voltage rail? Or can I just connect the VCC- pin to ground? I assume I can connect it right to ground because no signal is being amplified right?

Comment: No, it has to swing negative by the maximum positive input voltage, so if the maximum peak input voltage is, say, 7V, you should have a negative rail of about -10V or better (the LF351 needs about 3V more for the output stage).

Comment: Dang. Circuit just got much more complicated.

Comment: If I am connecting a smartphone to this rectifier, what rail voltages would you recommend? +5 and -5 V?

Comment: +5, -5 created from a 7660 and a couple capacitors, and pick a better op-amp, maybe a MCP662 dual. Simple.